# How to use ‘Wide Column’ feature in Cassandra?

Tags: c#, cassandra, cql, cql3

I checked the ranking in [DbEngine](http://db-engines.com/en/ranking/wide+column+store) about 'Wide Column Store' database, the `Cassandra` seems to be the widest choice at present.

If I understood correctly, the so called '*Wide Column*' means the columns for one row are dynamically, such as count and the name of columns, so it doesn't need the Schema stuffs.

But from most articles and documentations online, I found there is always '`CREATE TABLE (...)`' CQL query executed firstly, then insert the data with this schema. From my understanding, it's the '*Static Columns*' in Cassandra, which has a fixed schema defined. So how to insert data without creating the schema firstly?

And also, I found another item called '*Wide Row*', what does it exactly mean, any relations with the '*Wide Column*'?

Thanks a lot, the concepts puzzled me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 interfaces to access the data in Cassandra - Thrift and CQL.

Thrift is kinda low level and gives you access to "internal" rows (aka Wide rows), and also allows you to use schemaless (dynamic) tables/column families.

CQL tables are built on top of the internal rows, and can only be accessed via CQL. CQL tables allow you to use all modern features like collections, user-types and etc.

You can find more information there: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/thrift-to-cql3

Comment: There is also more detail in this blog post: [Does CQL support dynamic columns / wide rows?](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/does-cql-support-dynamic-columns-wide-rows).